# Want to upgrade my Windroy Emulator Android Version

Tags: android, android-fragments, sdk, android-emulator, windroy

I am currently using Windroy and would like to know if there is a manual way for me to upgrade my android system from 4.0.3 to 4.1 (or any version, doesn't matter really). How would I do that? Is there a package which I can download, and if I can, how would i install it to the Windroy emulator? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Windroy is no longer developed.
There is Windroye running Android 4.4 , but also this is not easy to be found.
Web site results closed; there is the following Facebook page as reference:
https://www.facebook.com/Windroy-782767791757850/

You could try alternatives, as MEMU, NOX, Andy, BlueStacks, Jar Of Beans, ...
https://emulation.miraheze.org/wiki/Android_emulators